# Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated

Tags: java, jpa, constraints, spring-transactions

I have this code, but I can't find where it creates this value which causes:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException at JobHousekeepingServiceIntegrationTest.java:280
        Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException at JobHousekeepingServiceIntegrationTest.java:280
            Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException at JobHousekeepingServiceIntegrationTest.java:280
```

```java
private void givenSeveralJobInstancesWithExecutionsInStatusForDate(
        final int count,
        final JobExecutionStatus status, 
        final LocalDateTime lastUpdate, 
        final List<Long> instanceIdsCreated) {

    new Transaction() {

        @Override
        protected void run() throws Exception {

            for (int n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
                JobInstanceEntityBuilder instBuilder = JobInstanceEntityBuilder.forDefinition(jobDef)
                        .withName("SOME_JOB" + n)
                        .withStatus(status)
                        .withParameters(
                            new JobInstanceParameterEntity("prop", "val" + n),
                            optionalDocAttachment(n),
                            optionalDocAttachment(n % 8)
                        )
                        .withLastUpdateTimestamp(lastUpdate);
                JobInstanceEntity inst = instBuilder.persist(getEM());
                instanceIdsCreated.add(inst.getId());

                JobExecutionEntityBuilder.forInstance(inst)
                        .onServerNodeName("NODE_X")
                        .withStatus(JobExecutionStatus.FAILED)
                        .withMessages(new JobExecutionMessageEntity(JobExecutionMessageCategory.ERROR, "error message " + n, null))
                        .withEndTime(lastUpdate)
                        .persist(getEM());
                if (status != null) {
                    // execution but no queue entry anymore
                    JobExecutionEntityBuilder.forInstance(inst)
                            .onServerNodeName("NODE_X")
.withStatus(status)
                            .withMessages(new JobExecutionMessageEntity(JobExecutionMessageCategory.INFO, "info message " + n, null))
                            .withEndTime(lastUpdate)
                            .persist(getEM());
                } else {
                    // queue entry but no execution
                    getEM().persist(new QueuedJobInstanceEntity(inst));
                }

                instBuilder.forceUpdateTimestamp(getEM());
            }
        }
    }.executeWithCommit();
}
```

Comment: Exception that you get is actually from executing some query against DB. It would help to review what exact SQL query (and with which data) is executed and what specific constraint (that are defined in accessed database) is violated. It would help to understand what data needs to be changed to not violate constraint (or remove that constraint)

Comment: That is a very modified stack trace too as all the causes are thrown from the same line of code in your test. The exception cause from the database should tell you the constraint violated, and EclipseLink usually includes the query that caused the problem in the message. If you really cannot which of these persist calls is the problem, try ensuring flush is called after your persist calls, as it will immediately force the insert to synchronize to the database instead of waiting until the commit.